# Authentication failed while updating (deploying) application on google app engine via command prompt in java windows 7

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt

I am trying to update (deploying) my app through Command prompt in java. its getting failed and showing below message:-

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Bad authentication response: 404 Not Found
Unable to update app: Bad authentication response: 404 Not Found
Please see the logs [C:\Users\Shree\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg6374544163646389530
.log] for further information.
```

I am updating using command :-

```
appcfg.cmd update "war path"
```

after this command, I entered my email id and password correctly then its showing above message

why authentication getting failed?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that "war path" is the path to your files, I'd check your application tag. The application id may not be correct.

Comment: Savion thank u for your response. my application id is correct because i can deploy it through eclipse google plug in but when i deploy it through Command Prompt its getting failed.

Comment: Have you tried elevating your command prompt? Run as administrator. You may be hitting a firewall from windows.